# Multidimensional Fourier transform: inner product in exponential?

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a basic and not very deep understanding of continuous and discrete Fourier transforms in one dimension.

In a multidimensional Fourier transform, the exponent of $e$ includes the inner product of the arguments of the original function and the transformed function.  I'm having trouble finding an explanation of why this is the right way to extend the idea of a Fourier transform to more than one dimension.  What is the intuition, or perhaps a more formal reason for this idea?  In one dimension, the original function's and transformed function's arguments are multiplied, and using an inner product in a multidimensional case is one natural extension of that idea, but that's not enough to justify it.

I see that using the inner product in the exponential means that the integral or sum (for a discrete Fourier transform) is over a product of $\cos x_i + i \sin x_i$ sums, but I am not sure why that makes sense, or even whether that's a useful way to think about it.  (I can picture waves in two real dimensions, and multiplying one-dimensional wave equations kind of feels like a good way to represent that, but I still don't have a clear understanding.)

Pointers to texts as well as explanations here would be welcome.

Comment: Since $\exp(ix\cdot \xi) = \exp(\sum ix_j\xi_j) = \prod \exp(ix_j\xi_j)$ its just fourier transforming repeatedly in each dimension

Comment: It is exponential law. Multiplication of two exp-expressions adds the exponents.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, thanks--but why is multiplying the way to do that?  (Contrast: You can't use multiplication to analyze a multidimensional probability distribution unless the marginal r.v.s are independent.  I recognize that this is a different case, but the general lesson, for me, is that you have to have a reason that multiplication is appropriate.)

Comment: I am not claiming that the integrals split into a product of integrals. You should explicitly write out the repeated Fourier transform $\mathcal F_x \mathcal F_y [u]$ ie once in $y$ then once in $x$ and use what I said.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinKhor.  OK, I see that:  When I apply the single-dimensional FT twice, I can combine the $\exp$s.  I guess the assumption is that one can decompose a function over two variables into a sum of waves that are perpendicular/orthogonal to each other (and then generalize that to higher dimensions). Given that a continuous FT can decompose nearly anything into periodic functions--so why not just choose to do it this way?--it makes sense.

Comment: Re suspicion, it doesn't work for an arbitrary function but things work out if you add some technical assumptions. If you're working with a random variable then its characteristic function(which always exists) is the fourier transform of its law, and the characteristic function completely determines the law.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinKhor.  I will think about that.  I kind of knew that about characteristic functions but had forgotten for the moment and didn't have it in mind.  (I had deleted the "suspicion" comment at the last minute.  For other readers, it was that I was suspicious of decomposing into orthogonal wavesbecause of probability-trained intuitions).

Comment: @CalvinKhor I feel that you ought to get an answer out of this discussion, although you are not in need of rep.  If you're busy, I suppose that if you copy what you wrote into an answer, I could edit in the details that you led me to work out.  Kind of like lecture notes written by a student.

Comment: Well, part of the reason I did not post an answer was that I wasn't sure what details to use, e.g. which fourier transform etc. In particular I don't really understand the DFT very well, so if thats your primary motivation then I don't feel very qualified. Also, I'm a little busy :) but you can answer your own question if you want, then ping me and I can give that a read when you're done

Comment: @CalvinKhor, I posted an answer for continuous a continuous Fourier transform.  If that looks OK, I'll add a discrete version as well.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Or maybe I won't add anything more about DFT except for the note at the end that I just added.  DFT has some tricks and variations (which I'm still learning), but it's clear that the basic structure of iterated sums and products of $\exp$s is going to produce the same result.

Comment: @Mars Yeah I think the note is fine. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Following @CalvinKhor's suggestions in comments, including the suggestion that I post an answer:

First treat $f(x,y)$ as a function of $x$, and apply a Fourier transform to define $H(\omega,y)$ as a function of $\omega$ for fixed $y$:

$$H(\omega,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)\,e^{-i\omega x}dx$$

Now apply a Fourier transform to the result with respect to $y$, to define a function $F$ as a function of $\xi$:

$$F(\omega,\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(\omega,y)\,e^{-i\xi y}dy = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)\,e^{-i\omega x}dx\right)e^{-i\xi y}dy =$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)\,e^{-i(\omega x + \xi y)} dx \, dy$$

This shows that the inner product of the two vectors inside the transform is simply the result of iteratively applying the Fourier transform to different component variables.  One can repeat the process for more dimensions.

You can combine the integrals if you want to treat them as a single integral applying to vectors as such.

(I think it's pretty clear that the same strategy will work with a discrete Fourier transform.  There are some nuances for DFT that have to be specified, but in the end you are doing the same sort of thing with sums instead of integrals.)